# OpenCV and python3

Tags: pi-3, opencv

I recently installed opencv but before I run the python script i always have to run these two commands:

```
workon cv
source ~/.profile
```

I already tried running the commands at boot, here's my '/etc/rc.local':

```
#!/bin/sh -e

IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

/home/pi/boot.sh
# boot.sh contains those two commands
exit 0
```

but it didn't work.

I even tried using `crontab -e`, but that too didn't work

Is there any other way by which i can avoid typing those commands in future?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is in any way specific to the Raspberry Pi. You might have more luck [so] or [unix.se].

Answer (score 2):

Have you made sure you're file is executable?

Try changing /home/pi/boot.sh to say this:

```
#!/bin/bash
workon cv
source /home/pi/profile
```

Then make the file executable with the following command:

```
chmod +x /home/pi/boot.sh
```

Also, rc.local is run as root so ~/profile would mean /root/profile instead of /home/pi/profile.